# Alternative to io.MultiReader for copying multiple files

Tags: go

Is there an alternative to io.MultiReader for copying multiple file parts at once?

Apparently io.MultiReader open each source file and appends its contents to the destination file.

Unfortunately the destination file doesn't support appending data (it is a S3 object).

Merging the file parts and then sending it is not a viable solution, as it takes up a lot more time.

My code (fs is an interface from https://github.com/pydio/cells/blob/main/gateway/dav/filesystem.go):

```
...
dstFile, err := fs.OpenFile(ctx, dst, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
readers := make([]io.Reader, 0, len(children))
for _, item := range children {
    source := path.Join(dir, name)
    srcFile, err := fs.OpenFile(ctx, source, os.O_RDONLY, 0)
    readers = append(readers, srcFile)
}
multiSources := io.MultiReader(readers...)
writtenBytes, err := io.Copy(dstFile, multiSources)
...
```

I expected the destination file to contain the data from all file parts, but it only contains the last part.

My solution:

```
myReader := io.TeeReader(multiSources, io.Discard)
_, err = io.Copy(dstFile, myReader)
```

io.Copy is necessary because dstFile does not implement the Writer interface

Comment: ?? Just do it one file after the other. The use of a io.MultiReader is wrong here.

Comment: Typo? The code in the question uses the same source file name on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the files one by one.  MultiReader is not needed.

```
var writtenBytes int64
dstFile, err := fs.OpenFile(ctx, dst, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
defer dstFile.Close()
for _, item := range children {
    srcFile, err := fs.OpenFile(ctx, path.Join(dir, item), os.O_RDONLY, 0)
    if err != nil {
        // add code to handle error
    }
    n, err := io.Copy(dstFile, srcFile)
    writtenBytes += n
    srcFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        // add code to handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: dstFile does not support append. This is the problem.

Comment: @JaimeSilva Are you saying that the application cannot call dstFile.Write more than one time?  This contradicts the question where it's stated that dstFile is a stream.  It will help if you edit the question to show exactly what `fs` is (package name, etc).

Comment: I have edit it.  fs is from https://github.com/pydio/cells/blob/main/gateway/dav/filesystem.go

Comment: @JaimeSilva The destination file implementation does not have a useful implementation of the io.Writer interface ([the Write method returns immediately with an error](https://github.com/pydio/cells/blob/b76cba25ddeb37de37fea5fa39309c4d9bfeb552/gateway/dav/filesystem.go#L381)).  I have no idea how to use that package.

Comment: I have edit the Writer interface to return nil instead of err, and added two lines to my code. Now it is working:
myReader := io.TeeReader(multiSources, io.Discard)
_, err = io.Copy(dstFile, myReader)